# how to use group by function for DbFunctions.DiffMinutes

Tags: linq

I have this Linq query.I want to show ab.InTime and DbFunctions value together

```
var sdv = (from ab in db.Attendances
                       where ab.Employee == 63 && ab.InTime.Value.Year == 2015 && ab.InTime.Value.Month == 8
                       select ab.InTime,DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(ab.InTime, ab.OutTime) / 60);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you can use `select new{...}`. Please try this:

```
var sdv = (from ab in db.Attendances
           where ab.Employee == 63 && ab.InTime.Value.Year == 2015 && ab.InTime.Value.Month == 8
           select new{
                      InTime=ab.InTime,
                      Minutes=DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(ab.InTime, ab.OutTime) / 60)
                     };
```